# Determining the order within subscribe()

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I have a function in my `component.ts` file. What I want to do is to make sure that `uploadFile()` operation is completed before `this.isModalOpen=false` , `this.form.reset()`  and  `this.list.get()` are executed. My code works just fine but I want to do this to avoid potential problems in the future. If someone can propose a solution and also explain to me the logic behind it, I would appreciate it.

```
save() {
    if (this.form.invalid) {
      return;
    }
    
    if(this.selectedCandidate.id){
      this.candidateService.update(this.selectedCandidate.id, this.form.value).subscribe(()=>{
        if(this.form.get('file').value){
          this.uploadFile(this.selectedCandidate.id);
        }
        this.isModalOpen=false; 
        this.form.reset(); 
        this.list.get(); });
    }
    else{
      this.candidateService.create(this.form.value).subscribe((candidateCreate)=>{
        if(this.form.get('file').value){
          this.uploadFile(candidateCreate.id);
        }
        this.isModalOpen=false; 
        this.form.reset(); 
        this.list.get();
      });
    }
  }
```

`uploadFile()` is just a function to upload a pdf file.

```
uploadFile(id:string){
    const formData = new FormData();
    var SERVER_URL =  `https://localhost:44310/api/app/cv/${id}/upload-cv`;
    formData.append('file', this.form.get('file').value);
    this.httpClient.post<any>(SERVER_URL,formData).subscribe((res) => console.log(res), (err) => console.log(err));
  }
```

Comment: What does the uploadFile function look like?

Comment: @MathewBerg I added uploadFile to my original question.

Comment: Add a flag to your object; before they've uploaded the file, set it to false. In the `subscribe`, set it to true. In `save`, if it is false, `return` immediately.

Comment: I was actually wondering if it was possible to do this with different operators. For instance, ```concatMap```.

Answer (score 0):

Can you change your upload File function return the observable instead? If you need to catch the error wire up a catchError pipe.

```
uploadFile(id:string){
    const formData = new FormData();
    var SERVER_URL =  `https://localhost:44310/api/app/cv/${id}/upload-cv`;
    formData.append('file', this.form.get('file').value);
    return this.httpClient.post<any>(SERVER_URL,formData)
  }
```

```
this.candidateService.create(this.form.value).subscribe((candidateCreate)=>{
        if(this.form.get('file').value){
          this.uploadFile(candidateCreate.id)
            .subscribe(() => this.isModelOpen=false);
        }
        else {
          this.isModalOpen=false; 
          this.form.reset(); 
          this.list.get();
        }
      });
```

Comment: I just tried to change uploadFile as you have shown but I can't seem to do subscribe on uploadFile. It says : "Property 'subscribe' does not exist on type 'void'".

Comment: Did you put in the return?

Comment: You're right, this works. I actually made another mistake somewhere else in my code.

Answer (score 0):

If you make your `uploadFile` method return an observable:

```js
uploadFile(id:string): Observable<any> {
    const formData = new FormData();
    var SERVER_URL = `https://localhost:44310/api/app/cv/${id}/upload-cv`;
    formData.append('file', this.form.get('file').value);

    return this.httpClient.post<any>(SERVER_URL, formData);
}
```

You could do something like this:

```js
save() {
    if (this.form.invalid) {
      return;
    }
    
    operation$ = this.selectedCandidate.id 
        ? this.candidateService.update(this.selectedCandidate.id, this.form.value)
        : this.candidateService.create(this.form.value);

    request$ = operation$.pipe(
        switchMap(canidate => this.form.get('file').value
            ? this.uploadFile(candidate.id)
            : of(undefined)
        )
    );

    reqeust$.subscribe(() => {
        this.isModalOpen = false; 
        this.form.reset(); 
        this.list.get();
    }));
}
```

The idea here is to use build a single observable (`request$`) that will emit once all of your "work" is done.  We define `request$` to begin with `operation$` piping its emission into a [`switchMap`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/switchmap).

We pass a function that returns an observable into `switchMap`; the function returns either the call to `uploadFile()` or an observable that instantly emits `undefined` (*indicating no file was uploaded*) using [`of`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/creation/of).

This "inner observable" is subscribed to automatically by `switchMap` and its emissions are emitted.

Now, we can simply subscribe to `request$` and receive an emission whenever the work is done.  Therefore, anything inside your `subscribe()` will only be executed after the work is done.